# Hide/Show component using componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a loading spinner component to display using `componentDidUpdate` which sets the `state` to `true`. The loader doesn't show, just a white space until the `buildPosts()` renders. How can I display the `Loader` component while the function executes?

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {loaded: false};
}


onLoaded(){
    this.setState({loaded: true });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.onLoaded();
}

buildPosts(posts) {
    return posts.map(post =>
        <Post post={post} key={post.id} />
    );
}
render() {
    const { posts, totalPages, pageNum = 1 } = this.props;


    return (
        this.state.loaded ? 
        (<div id="blog">
            {this.buildPosts(posts)}
            {this.buildPagination(parseInt(pageNum), totalPages)}
        </div>) : <Loader /> 
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the loader never shows up? or that it shows up initially but not exactly when you are wanting it too? The way the code looks is, it would come in with a loader, once updated it sets loader to false, and then on next render it builds the posts, but it wont ever build posts and have the <Loader displaying with how this is currently put together

Comment: Did you bind `onLoaded` to the correct value of `this`? React only automatically binds its own lifecycle functions, you must manually bind any you add to the class, e.g. with `this.onLoaded.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your loader will be showed when there is no post. You may not need the `load` state. How about this way :

```
  render() {
    const { posts, totalPages, pageNum = 1 } = this.props;


        return (
            posts !== undefined && posts.length > 0 ? 
            (<div id="blog">
                {this.buildPosts(posts)}
                {this.buildPagination(parseInt(pageNum), totalPages)}
            </div>) : <Loader /> 
        );
  }
```